# Subheading at start of paragraph in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I'm currently writing my master thesis in LibreOfficeWriter, and the formatting is specified by the American Psychology Association.
Basically, there are different levels of headings, where level 
three is indented, bold, upper and lower case and the text follows immediately after the heading, which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQLAA.png).

Now I've tried and googled, but I haven't figured out how to create such a heading where text immediately follows with a different paragraph style. I'd need it to be a paragraph style so I could include the heading into the table of contents.

Is it possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not officially supported, according to [Header and Paragraph on Text on Same Line](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=351660) (although that's an OpenOffice site, it looks like it's the same in LibreOffice - found via this thread: [[libreoffice-users] Same-line headings? (feature discussion)](https://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg05282.html)).

But there is a way to mimic it: see [[Tutorial] "In-line" or "run-in" headings](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=709). That thread invites you to download an .odt document with an embedded macro, but if you don't enable the macro the document gives enough explanation of the technique.

In summary, the "real" headings are put on lines of their own, but *formatted in white (ie invisible) and very small (to minimise vertical space)*. Then the next paragraph starts with a couple of *Chapter fields that copy the heading number and text*, followed by the regular text inline. To edit heading text you'd need to edit the invisible text, then automatic field updating will make it display in the visible fields.

This may be more cumbersome than you are prepared to deal with!